# Glassfish 3 has two configurations

Tags: glassfish-3

I wanted to setup JDBC realm in Glassfish 3.1 and I am following this blog http://blog.gamatam.com/2009/11/jdbc-realm-setup-with-glassfish-v3.html

But I notice in Glassfish 3.1 that there are two configuration namely **default-config** and **server-config**

I just wanted to try out authentication using glassfish but I dont know where should I configure my realm?

Any hints?

Thanks

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Put it in *server-config*.

From the [Glassfish 3.1.1 doc](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2426/abdjl.html):

> The default-config configuration is a special configuration that acts
>   as a template for creating named configurations. Clusters and
>   instances cannot refer to the default-config configuration. The
>   default-config configuration can only be copied to create
>   configurations.