# Glassfish 3.1.2 - Difference Between default-config and server-config

Tags: configuration, glassfish-3

What is the difference between default-config and server-config?  If I want to adjust a thread pool size for example, do I need to do it in both places?  If just one, which one?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Glassfish 3 has two configurations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10188342/glassfish-3-has-two-configurations)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It appears that the default-config is used by Glassfish as a template to create other configs, so anything you actually want to configure on a server should go in the server-config.

Also see [Glassfish 3 has two configurations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10188342/glassfish-3-has-two-configurations)